# How to add file browsing window to Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, plugins

I've been looking into the plugin manager for this, but when i installed the "Explorer" plugin, it totally crashed the application.
I was unable to launch it again, untill i removed the .dll from the plugins directory.

Any insights on this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing all of your Notepad++ plugins. Then reinstall only the Explorer plugin. If it works, then another Notepad++ plugin that you had installed was probably interfering with the Explorer plugin.

Comment: Worked removing some old unused plugins. Thanks !